# justPy toggle a Quasar drawer

Tags: python, justpy

I copied some HTML from Quasar for a page layout with a drawer and can not figure out how to toggle the drawer (sidebar). The button works to hide the drawer, but can not get it visible again.  Or if you have an example or can point me in direction of a non-Quasar sidebar that works in a similar manner, that would be helpful.

```py
    def show_drawer(self,msg):
        self.wbDrawer.show = True
    
    def toggle_show_drawer(self, msg):
        self.wbDrawer.show = not self.wbDrawer.show
    
    def toggle_visible_drawer(self, msg):
        if self.wbDrawerDiv.visibility_state == 'visible':
            self.wbDrawerDiv.set_class('invisible')
            self.wbDrawerDiv.visibility_state = 'invisible'
        else:
            self.wbDrawerDiv.set_class('visible')
            self.wbDrawerDiv.visibility_state = 'visible'
    
    
            self.btn1.visibility_state = 'visible'
    
    def quasar_print():
        wp = jp.QuasarPage()
        c = jp.parse_html(html_string, a=wp)
        for i in c.commands:
            print(i)
        return wp
    
    def quasar_page():
        wp = jp.QuasarPage()
        wp.data["drawer"] = "open"
        root = jp.Div(a=wp)
    
        c1 = jp.Div(classes='q-pa-md', a=root)
        wbLayout = jp.QLayout(view='hHh Lpr lff', container=True, style='height: 300px', classes='shadow-2 rounded-borders', a=c1)
        wbHeader = jp.QHeader(elevated=True, classes='bg-black', a=wbLayout)
        wbToolbar = jp.QToolbar(a=wbHeader)
        wbToolbarBtn = jp.QBtn(flat=True, round=True, dense=True, icon='menu', a=wbToolbar,click=toggle_visible_drawer)
        wbToolbarTitle = jp.QToolbarTitle(a=wbToolbar, text='Header')
        wbDrawerDiv = jp.Div(a=wbLayout)
        wbDrawer = jp.QDrawer(  width=200, breakpoint=500, bordered=True, classes='bg-grey-3', a=wbDrawerDiv, model=[wp, 'drawer'])     
        wbScrollArea = jp.QScrollArea(classes='fit', a=wbDrawer)
        c9 = jp.QList(a=wbScrollArea)
        c10 = jp.Div(a=c9, text='scroll area')
        btn1 = jp.Button(text='Hide me', a=wbScrollArea)
    
        wbPageContainer = jp.QPageContainer(a=wbLayout)
        wbPage = jp.QPage(padding=True, a=wbPageContainer)
        pageText = jp.Div(a=wbPage, text='page container')
    
    
        btnSideBar = jp.Button(text="button on SideBar", a=wbScrollArea)
        
        # try both visible and show
        btnVisible = jp.QBtn(text="toggle_visible_drawer", a=wbPage,click=toggle_visible_drawer)
        btnShow = jp.QBtn(text="toggle_visible_drawer",  a=wbPage,click=toggle_show_drawer)
    
        return wp
    
    jp.justpy(quasar_page)
```

Comment: There is a lot of code that is not related to your question. Could you please make the code shorter and to the point of you question?

Comment: also the html_string is missing

Answer (score 1):

```
import justpy as jp


def toggle_visible_drawer(self, msg):
    self.drawer.value = not self.drawer.value


def quasar_page():
    wp = jp.QuasarPage()

    btn_drawer = jp.QBtn(
        flat=True,
        round=True,
        dense=True,
        icon="menu",
        a=wp,
        click=toggle_visible_drawer,
    )

    wp_layout = jp.QLayout(a=wp)
    PageContainer = jp.QPageContainer(a=wp_layout)
    pageText = jp.Div(a=PageContainer, text="page container")

    drawer = jp.QDrawer(
        width=200,
        breakpoint=500,
        bordered=True,
        a=wp_layout,
    )
    btn_drawer.drawer = drawer
    ScrollArea = jp.QScrollArea(classes="fit", a=drawer)
    c2 = jp.Div(a=ScrollArea, text="scroll area left")

    return wp

jp.justpy(quasar_page)
```

https://github.com/justpy-org/justpy/blob/9aa6a8264da7317f25ed3a01266d7d5dca99e0d9/justpy/quasarcomponents.py#L2651

Comment: @Wolfgang is it possible to submit a PR to add this as an example for another Quasar component in this guide https://justpy.io/quasar_tutorial/quasar_components/ ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).